# Erro ao instalar Magento no Windows 10

Tags: magento, instalador, windows-10

Para sempre nos 50%. Alguém da uma luz??

`Module 'Magento_Directory':
Installing data... 
[ERROR] PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'AD' for key 'PRIMARY' in...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta está na própria mensagem de erro:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'AD' for key 'PRIMARY' in...

Você tem uma tabela que possui um campo com restrição de unicidade (*"unique key"*), e o instalador tenta inserir na tabela um registro com um valor já existente.

Reveja seu instalador, ou remova a entrada que possui o valor repetido, e tente instalar novamente.

Comment: Cara.. eu tava fazendo coisa errada aqui.. já tinha apagado o banco, mas o banco errado. Instalei duas versões de mysql, por isso não tava dando certo... mas valeu!